# Scheduled Tasks and Environment Variables

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task

I have a scheduled task, a batch file, that uses an environment variables which is set system-wide.

On server 1, the scheduled task runs under a domain account and the environment variable works. The environment variable also exists in my session and when I runas as the service account.

On server 2, the scheduled task runs under a different domain account and the environment variable DOES NOT work. However, the environment variable does exist in my session and when I runas as the service account.

On both servers the environment variable has been set system-wide by the same script originally. The script runs again every now and then and as far as I can see noone has tempered with the environment variable.

The scheduled tasks are set up identically on the two servers (using the same XML file) and the two service accounts are identically configured (as far as I know).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error code returned by scheduled task?

Comment: It returns whatever error code I tell it to return. The scheduled task is my batch file.

Comment: I mean errors returned by Task Scheduler, under Last Run Result column. If the task is completed successfully - you get 0x0, if Not - something else.

Comment: I get the error code my batch file returns. It happens to be 1 since that is what my batch file returns when it finds the environment variable empty.

Comment: have you restarted server 2 after applying environment variables? See  this [reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821761)

Comment: No. And I see no indication that that would influence the scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by allowing the scheduled task to "run with highest privileges" on both servers.

I don't know why that helps but apparently on server 2 the domain account just doesn't see the environment variables when not run with highest privileges.

Comment: Good!
Have you tried to use working account on 2nd server to see if it works  without "run with highest privileges" ?

Comment: No. Each server has a domain account assigned for this purpose. I cannot move them around. I shouldn't even know the password for the account.